# Client Side Validation for Hidden Input in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hidden-field, client-side-validation

I'm still a bit novice to the ASP.NET MVC architecture.  I have an Edit page for data, which includes a hidden input.  After testing my page, the 'Save' button wasn't doing anything and after some research learned it was a client-side validation issue.

After commenting the following line in the page:

```
 @*@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)*@
```

(where ID is a GUID), the page validated and posted.

From what I recall, the scaffolding put this code into my view.  I just need to know how to fix this so that the ID field gets sent back properly to the controller and wanted to know why it wasn't validating.

Here is my View's code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>

        <div class="object_basics">
      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>


       <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add the validation message for the ID ?

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Client side validation for hidden fields not working, because jQuery validation ignore all hidden tags. 
You must define `HiddenRequiredValidator` class to achieve your goal.

You can read a solution to solve this problem [Here](http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/02/validating-hidden-fields-in-asp-net-mvc-2/)

Answer (score 0):

**In view**, update from:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

To

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new{ID = model.ID}))
```

Remove the hidden element [@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)].

**In your controller**, update the action properties like below

```
public ActionResult YourActionName(string ID, string Title)
```

Hopefully, this answers your question.

Cheers,
Danny

Comment: I still was curious to know why having a hidden input for one of the model's property's value is wrong/doesn't-work.

Comment: It's not wrong and it still works if you use the action property like above. I think the reason why urs failed is because Action is expecting integer type for ID property.